# Unable to set SlidingPaneLayout to invisible

Tags: android, slidingpanelayout

I'm trying to create an app which has a MapFragment in a sliding pane. The map is on a fragment which slides open into the main content, a ListView. However, I'm unable to have the MapFragment completely hidden as there is always a portion of it visible on the main view.
Here is my code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <ListView
                android:id="@+id/postsView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                >
        </ListView>


            <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"

                    />


    </android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the nature of `SlidingPaneLayout`. It always shows a slice of the opposite pane, to help indicate to users how to switch between the panes. I do not see any option in its API to change that, though it's possible there is a way to do so via a style.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is there some example of an style which does so, which you could point me to ?

Comment: I've seen the Google+ android app doing so

Comment: @tinker: What evidence do you have that the Google+ app is using `SlidingPaneLayout`? AFAIK, they are using `DrawerLayout` (or their own workalike), which is a completely separate thing (albeit one with some UI similarities).